# How to find the distinct values with total number of rows?

Tags: php, mysql

I want result in a single query.

Currently, I am using 2 queries. First for the distinct rows and the second is for the count rows. Second query fire for each row of the first query. Which is not good for the server.

I tried it in a single query but it shows count as 1 for each row which is wrong. I don't know how to do it in a single query.

Please help!

2 queries:

```
SELECT DISTINCT `_car_make`.`id` as `make_id`, `_car_make`.`title`
FROM `_motor`, `_car_make`
WHERE `_motor`.`make` = `_car_make`.`id`
AND `domain` = 'domain.com' AND `active` = 'y' AND `_motor`.`status` != 'SOLD'
GROUP BY `_motor`.`id` ORDER BY `_car_make`.`title`

SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT `id`) AS `TOTAL_MAKE` FROM `_motor` 
WHERE `_motor`.`make` = '$make_id' 
AND `domain` = 'domain.com'  AND `_motor`.`status` != 'SOLD' AND `active` = 'y'
```

I tried it in 1 query, which shows count as 1 which is wrong:

```
SELECT DISTINCT `_car_make`.`id` as `make_id`, `_car_make`.`title`, count(`_motor`.`id`) AS TotalMake
FROM `_motor`, `_car_make`
WHERE `_motor`.`make` = `_car_make`.`id`
AND `domain` = 'domain.com' AND `active` = 'y' AND `_motor`.`status` != 'SOLD'
GROUP BY `_motor`.`id` ORDER BY `_car_make`.`title`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try below-

```
SELECT `_car_make`.`id` as `make_id`, `_car_make`.`title`, count(*) AS TotalMake
FROM `_motor` inner join `_car_make`
on `_motor`.`make` = `_car_make`.`id`
AND `domain` = 'coxheathcarcentre.co.uk' 
where `active` = 'y' AND `_motor`.`status` != 'SOLD'
GROUP BY `_car_make`.`id`,`_car_make`.`title`
ORDER BY `_car_make`.`title`
```